# How to search column in database for match to user input

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to query a postgresql database to check for a match to what the user inputs.  For example, if the user enters a user name of 'user1', I want to search the username column in the users table of the database to find a match to the user name.

My database collection works, and when using the query (select * from users;) I am getting correct information displayed in the console. When I run the following query in PGAdmin or terminal I am getting correct results (select username from users where username = 'user1';).

- In java application User.getUserName() is a getter which returns the userName set by the application when the user is prompted to enter their user name on the account registration page.

Code as follows:

```
public static void isUniqueUser(String userName) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bigday", "postgres", "admin");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select from users where username = " + User.getUserName());
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        //if name found in db prompt name already taken
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("User Name: " + rs.getString(1) + "Password: " 
                    + rs.getString(2) + "Email: " + rs.getString(3) + "Phone: " + rs.getString(4));
        }

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I run the query in Eclipse this is what is returned in the console:

ERROR: column "user1" does not exist
  Position: 36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the `String` (with `'` characters), or *better* use a bind parameter. And specify some columns (or use splat, `*`). Like,

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where username = ?");
stmt.setString(1,  User.getUserName());
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```